# Android icon error

Tags: android, icons, bitmap, graphic

I copied this code from a tutorial site because I am trying to learn it. But I am getting an error at

```
package com.android.test;
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
public class Rotate extends Activity {
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
```

**On this last line, I get an error where ".icon" is written. It says, "icon cannot be resolved or is not a field."**

> int width = bitmap.getWidth();
>          int height = bitmap.getHeight();
>
> ```
>    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
>    matrix.postRotate(90);
>
>    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
> ```
>
> width,
>            height, matrix, true);
>          BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBitmap);
>
> ```
>    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
>    imageView.setImageDrawable(bmd);
>    imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
>
>    linearLayout.addView(imageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
>      LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
>    setContentView(linearLayout);
>      }
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 7):

In your `import` statements, you have

```
import android.R;
```

That means it'll look in for `android.R.drawable.icon`, rathern than `R.drawable.icon`. `android.R` contains the IDs to all the assets from the SDK. To access your own assets, you need to remove the using statement, or manually write `com.your.package.name.R.drawable.icon`

Answer (score 6):

Icon some times works and some times it does not. Change it to 'ic_launcher'. This works all the time. This is the file name found under 'res/drawable-?dpi'.
It is the icon that appears on the android device.

Like this:
.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely because you don't have a image in your /res/drawable folder called icon.png/icon.bmp/icon.jpg

So, copy the image probably on the site in to that folder and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy an image called `icon.png` into the `res/drawable` directory.